# C++ Find last ocurrence of a string inside a substring

Tags: c++, boost, range, string-algorithm

I need a method that helps me to find a string inside another substring, or in other words, find a string inside a subrange of other string. Besides, I need to find it in reverse order because I know that the string I'm looking for is closed to the end of the substring used as "haystack".

Let's suppose the following piece of code, where `rfind_in_substr` is the method I'm asking for:

```
std::string sample("An example with the example word example trice");

// substring "ample with the example wo"
std::size_t substr_beg = 5;
std::size_t substr_size = 24;

// (1)
std::size_t pos = rfind_in_substr(sample, substr_beg,
                                  substr_size, "example");

// pos == 20, because its the index of the start of the second
// "example" word inside the main string.
```

Of course, the line (1) could be replaced by:

```
std::size_t pos = substr_beg + sample.substr
            (substr_beg, substr_size).rfind("example");
```

But that implies an unnecesary copy of the substring. Is there any method or C++/boost method that could help me doing that?

I was looking at `boost::algorithm::string` library but I've found nothing (that I had understood). I know that C++17 has the `std::string_view` class, that would be perfect, but I'm using C++14.

Comment: What's wrong with the [std::string::rfind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind)?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind I can't spot _unnecessary copies_ with that.

Comment: @user0042 `rfind` uses the whole string as "haystack", but the string I'm looking for must be found only in a subrange of the full string.

Comment: @user0042 `substr` returns a new string.

Comment: @Peregring-lk `rfind()` yields the pos. What's the problem to represent the _subrange_ from the original string using that information? Who ever was talking about `substr()`? You can easily calculate the iterator range with pos and known length.

Comment: @user0042 because if I use `rfind` over the full string, it will find the last ocurrence of `"example"`, and I don't want that. I need the second one because it's the one inside the substring I need (but I want to avoid a creation of a new string because my string is the contents of a big file). My english maybe is not good, but please read the code snippet and the expected output carefully.

Comment: This is a very non-trivial question, I really don't understand all the downvotes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's of course trivial regarding to calculation of the iterator range. Ending up with a `substr()` induced copy is just an XY-problem.

Comment: @user0042 I don't see it as trivial. If you could please post a solution that does not make a copy of the substring, I'll be the first to upvote your answer.

Comment: @user0042 Please if you think you are right, write a working solution that yields `pos == 20` without using `substr` or any other method involving copies.

Comment: @Peregring-lk You can use a two pass `rfind()` with a bit of math and using the result of the 1st one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Boost.StringAlgo:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp>

auto haystack = boost::make_iterator_range(str.begin() + from, str.begin() + from + len);
auto found = boost::algorithm::find_last(haystack, needle);
```

Now, if you need to use this with other member functions from `std::string`, you need to do extra steps in converting a resulting range into an index like [this answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029695/1012936), but if you aren't, then simply use the range interface and avoid the `std::string`'s "helpful" methods.

Another option is to use `boost::string_ref` which is what `std::string_view` is basically based on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>


std::size_t rfind_in_substr(std::string const& str, std::size_t from,
                            std::size_t len, std::string const& s)
{

    return from + boost::string_ref(str).substr(from, len).rfind(s);
}

int main()
{
    std::string sample("An example with the example word example trice");

    // substring "ample with the example wo"
    std::size_t substr_beg = 5;
    std::size_t substr_size = 24;

    // (1)
    std::size_t pos = rfind_in_substr(sample, substr_beg,
                                      substr_size, "example");

    // pos == 20, because its the index of the start of the second
    // "example" word inside the main string. 
    std::cout << pos << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer by combining an API that limits the search within the original string by length and an additional check to see if the end result comes prior to `substr_beg`:

```
std::size_t rfind_in_substr(
    const std::string& str
,   const std::size_t from
,   const std::size_t len
,   const std::string& sub
) {
    std::size_t res = str.rfind(sub, from+len-sub.size());
    return res != string::npos && res >= from ? res : string::npos;
}
```

- `from+len-sub.size()` computes the last position at which the substring could start.
- `res >= from` rejects an answer if it comes before the initial character of substring.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/lucpGp)

Comment: That implies to search to the beginning of `str` if the substring is not found. The think is that `str` is a very long `string` (it has a very long prefix before `from`).

Answer (score 2):

With `std::find_end` the problem can be solved efficiently without using more than needed, but I hoped there was any method that already solved that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::size_t rfind_in_substr(std::string const& str, std::size_t from,
                            std::size_t len, std::string const& s)
{
    auto sub_beg = str.begin() + from;
    auto sub_end = sub_beg + len;

    auto found_it = std::find_end(sub_beg, sub_end, s.begin(), s.end());

    if (found_it == sub_end)
        return str.npos;
    else
        return found_it - str.begin();
}

int main()
{
    std::string sample("An example with the example word example trice");

    // substring "ample with the example w"
    std::size_t substr_beg = 5;
    std::size_t substr_size = 24;

    std::size_t pos = rfind_in_substr(sample, substr_beg,
                                      substr_size, "example");

    std::cout << pos << std::endl; // Prints 20
}
```

Comment: Using some string_view+range goodness makes it _a lot_ more elegant in my opinion: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbe9b5dd0803ec61)**